# Directly validate Firebase token from react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I implemented Auth with Firebase + Facebook. To be able to use the Auth with my custom backend I implemented the admin SDK on my node Server. Now I am trying to validate if my Firebase token is still valid to know when I need to show the login screen. I could probably send the token to my custom backend. But since I don't need anything else from the backend, it would be easier to directly call firebase from the client.

Does someone know if a function like that exists?

Comment: use this package https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Firebase client SDKs periodically refresh the ID tokens and keep them alive. Therefore the token will remain valid, until the client explicitly invokes a sign out operation. See this discussion for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/rjR0zYiiEhM/Clt9aFtgAwAJ (It is a little old, but still relevant